# Python: Exceeding max recursion depth while calling superclass method from subclass

Tags: python, exception, inheritance, recursion

I've got an inheritance chain of three classes: Baz inherits from Bar inherits from Foo. I'd like to define a method in the Foo class that, when called in a subclass, returns the output of its parent class appended with stuff of its own. This is the desired output:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> baz = Baz()
>>> print foo.get_defining_fields()
['in Foo']
>>> print bar.get_defining_fields()
['in Foo', 'in Bar']
>>> print baz.get_defining_fields()
['in Foo', 'in Bar', 'in Baz']
```

The problem is, I'm misunderstanding something about the use of `super()` in superclass methods that are called by subclasses, or some other subclassing detail. This bit works fine:

```
>>> print foo.get_defining_fields()
['in Foo']
```

But `bar.get_defining_fields()` produces an infinite loop, running itself until a `RuntimeError` is raised instead of calling out to `foo.get_defining_fields` and stopping there like I want it to.

Here's the code.

```
class Foo(object):
    def _defining_fields(self):
        return ['in Foo']

    def get_defining_fields(self):
        if self.__class__ == Foo:
            # Top of the chain, don't call super()
            return self._defining_fields()
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_defining_fields() + self._defining_fields()

class Bar(Foo):
    def _defining_fields(self):
        return ['in Bar']

class Baz(Bar):
    def _defining_fields(self):
        return ['in Baz']
```

So `get_defining_fields` is defined in the superclass, and the `super()` call within it uses `self.__class__` in an attempt to pass the correct subclass name to the call in each subclass. When called in Bar, it resolves to `super(Bar, self).get_defining_fields()` so that the list returned by `foo.get_defining_fields()` would be prepended to the one returned by `far.get_defining_fields()`.

Probably a simple mistake if you properly understand Python's inheritance mechanics and the inner workings of `super()`, but since I obviously don't, I'd appreciate it if someone could point me to the proper way of doing this.

---

**EDIT**: as per Daniel Roseman's answer, I tried replacing the `super()` call with this form: `return super(Foo, self).get_defining_fields() + self._defining_fields()`

Now the infinite recursion no longer occurs, but I get a different error when calling `bar.get_defining_fields()`:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_defining_fields'
```

Something else is still amiss.

---

**EDIT**: yep, finally figured out what I was missing here. Marked Daniel's updated answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Charles Beattie: This is true for Python 3 where all classes are new-style classes, but not encouraged in Python 2.

Comment: I deleted my comment but I was asking before why he was deriving from object. Hence jena's reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 return super(self.__class__, self)...
```

`self.__class__` always refers to the *current* concrete class. So in Bar, it refers to Bar, and in Baz, it refers to Baz. So, Bar calls the superclass's method, but the `self.__class__` still refers to Bar, not Foo. So you will get an endless recursion.

That's why you must always refer to the class *specifically* in super. Like this:

```
return super(Foo, self)...
```

**Edit** Right, because only the top class defines `get_defining_fields`.

You're going about this the wrong way, really. This isn't a job for `super` at all. I think you might get better results iterating through `self.__class__.__mro__`, which is the way to access the method resolution order of the superclasses:

```
class Foo(object):
    def _defining_fields(self):
        return ['in Foo']

    def get_defining_fields(self):
        fields = []
        for cls in self.__class__.__mro__:
            if hasattr(cls, '_defining_fields'):
                fields.append(cls._defining_fields(self))
        return fields
```

¬

Comment: That solved the recursion, but brought about an AttributeError instead. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, my thinking was muddled, I was under the impression that Bar would inherit get_defining_fields as-is and running it from under Bar would make it "Bar's method" as far as the `super()` call was concerned.